# How can I change the Created By field for 1800 folders?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, splistitem, metadata, csv

I have a colleague who has written a powershell script to read URLs from a CSV file and create empty folders at those locations... 1800 of them.
The problem is they used their own named developer account to grant permissions to the script and so all the folders are listed as Created By `<Name of User>`.

The client requires the Created By field to read `<System Account>`. I know how to use powershell to modify a single list item:

```
##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = ""
$ListName= ""
$ID=1
$UserID=""
$TimeStamp = ""
 
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
 
#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
 
#Get the User
$User = $Ctx.Web.EnsureUser($UserID)
$ctx.Load($user)
 
#Get the list Item
$List=$Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$ListItem = $List.GetItemById($ID) 
$Ctx.Load($ListItem)
 
#update Created By column sharepoint online powershell
$ListItem["System Account"] = $User
#Update Modified By
$ListItem['System Account'] = $User
 
#Update List item
$ListItem.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
Write-host "Metadata values updated Successfully!" -f Green
```

Question: how can I modify this code to use the existing CSV file to change the Created By and Modified By columns of all 1800 folders?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest just authentication with App credentials.
Folders will be created on behalf of App name, not user name.

If you need to change "Created by" for existing folders,
try app authentication and Set-PnPListItem. This cmdlet allows to change fields including "Created By" and with "-UpdateType" parameter you can
set field values and does not create a new version.